# How to Filter NLTK's FreqDist counter using regex or pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nltk, counter

I have a FreqDist counter object, counting tuples with a set length. The length could be two or more, but it is the same within the counter object.

**For example:**

```
('a','b','c')   5
('a','b','d')   8
('c','d','a')   2
('a','a','e')   3
('a','b','e')   3
```

My objective is to filter the FreqDist counter, using the first two elements in this case, and identifying the tuple with the highest count. If the tuple contained two elements, then i would filter on the first only, always leaving the last one as a joker.

**step#1** filter on ('a','b', *)

```
('a','b','c')   5
('a','b','d')   8
('a','b','e')   3
```

**step#2** identify ('a','b','d') as the tuple with the highest count.

Surely there must be a method that can help do this, but my research did not reveal anything so far. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I put your data into a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'count':[5,8,2,3,3]},index=[('a','b','c'),('a','b','d') ,('c','d','a'),('a','a','e') ,('a','b','e')])

s=df.loc[list(filter(lambda x: (x[0] == 'a')&(x[1] == 'b'), df.index))]
s
Out[39]: 
           count
(a, b, c)      5
(a, b, d)      8
(a, b, e)      3

s.sort_values('count').tail(1)
Out[44]: 
           count
(a, b, d)      8
```

Comment: the counter has a length > hundreds of thousands